# Salesforce SFDX 2GP Packaging - Have an 0H id need a 04t id

Tags: salesforce, packaging

I created a package in VS Code to create a managed package using this command: `sfdx force:package:create --name "Test234" --packagetype "Managed" --targetdevhubusername DevHubTesting --path "force-app"`

I event got the response of :
`Result was Successfully created a package. 0HoGq000000PJzoKAY`

Can not figure out how to get the subscriber package id from this is id.

When I run the command `sfdx force:package:version:list` I get a `No results found`.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I needed to create a version after creating the package with this command:
`sfdx force:package:version:create --package "Test234" --installationkey test1234 --wait 10 -v DevHubTesting --codecoverage`

I hope that helps someone.